# three.js no camera collision with list collidable objects

Tags: three.js, camera, collision, frame-rate

in my scene i have one floor, 4 walls and 2 box. i use fps to control my camera. I make a list of collidable objets (colmeshList). but when i make a ray, have not hit intersect between camera and colmeshList. i din't understand where is my error and what i have not unterdstood.

```
`var scene, anbientLight, controls, camera, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh, bbox ;
        var collmeshList = [];
        var prevTime = performance.now();
        var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
animate();

function init() {

scene = new THREE.Scene();

ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x020202);
   scene.add(ambientLight);


//////WORLD
//FLOOR
floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 500 );
floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false } );
floorMesh = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
floorMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
floorMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
scene.add( floorMesh );

//WALLS
    W01Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 500, 200,0.001, 8,8 );
    W01Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
    W01Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( W01Geometry, W01Material );
   W01Mesh.position.z = -250;
   collmeshList.push (W01Mesh);
   scene.add( W01Mesh );

   W02Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 500, 200,0.001, 8,8 );
    W02Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
    W02Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( W02Geometry, W02Material );
   W02Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;
   W02Mesh.position.x = -250;
  //W01Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
   collmeshList.push (W02Mesh);
   scene.add( W02Mesh );

     W03Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 500, 200,0.001, 8,8 );
     W03Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
     W03Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( W03Geometry, W03Material );
     W03Mesh.rotation.y = -Math.PI/2;
     W03Mesh.position.x = 250;
     collmeshList.push (W03Mesh);
     scene.add( W03Mesh );

      W04Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 500, 200,0.001, 8,8 );
      W04Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
    W04Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( W04Geometry, W01Material );
    W04Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    W04Mesh.position.z = -250;
    collmeshList.push (W04Mesh);
    scene.add( W04Mesh );


    //wallGroup = new THREE.Group();
    //wallGroup.add(W01Mesh, W02Mesh, W03Mesh, W04Mesh);
    //wallGroup.position.y = 50;
    //scene.add(wallGroup);

    //OBSTACLES
    B01Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50,50 );
    B01Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
    B01Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( B01Geometry, B01Material );
    B01Mesh.position.z = -100;
    B01Mesh.position.y = 25;
    collmeshList.push (B01Mesh);
    scene.add( B01Mesh );

    B02Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50,50 );
    B02Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );
    B02Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( B02Geometry, B02Material );
    B02Mesh.position.z = 100;
    B02Mesh.position.y = 25;
    collmeshList.push (B02Mesh);
    scene.add( B02Mesh );


    //////PLAYER
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 50;
    camera.updateMatrix();


    //////CONTROLS CAMERA
   controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );
   scene.add( controls.getObject() );


  //////RENDU
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  }

  function clearText()
  {   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '..........';   }

  function appendText(txt)
  {   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += txt;   }

  function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  playerControls();

  //collupdate();




  renderer.render( scene, camera );

  }


        function playerControls () {

        //unlockAllDirection();



            // Are the controls enabled? (Does the browser have pointer lock?)
            if ( controls.controlsEnabled ) {

                // Save the current time
                var time = performance.now();
                // Create a delta value based on current time
                var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;

                // Set the velocity.x and velocity.z using the calculated time delta
                velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
                velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

                // As velocity.y is our "gravity," calculate delta
                velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass

                if ( controls.moveForward ) {
                    velocity.z -= 400.0 * delta;
                    // Nothing to do!
                }

                if ( controls.moveBackward ) {
                    velocity.z += 400.0 * delta;

                }

                if ( controls.moveLeft ) {
                    velocity.x -= 400.0 * delta;

                }

                if ( controls.moveRight ) {
                    velocity.x += 400.0 * delta;

                }


                // Update the position using the changed delta
                controls.getObject().translateX( velocity.x * delta );
                controls.getObject().translateY( velocity.y * delta );
                controls.getObject().translateZ( velocity.z * delta );

                // Prevent the camera/player from falling out of the 'world'
                if ( controls.getObject().position.y < 10 ) {

                    velocity.y = 0;
                    controls.getObject().position.y = 10;

                    }

                // Save the time for future delta calculations
                prevTime = time;

                }
        }

        function collupdate (){

  clearText();

  var cameraDirection = controls.getDirection(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)).clone();
  direction.applyQuaternion( cameraDirection.quaternion );
  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(controls.getObject().position, cameraDirection);    
  var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(collmeshList, true);  
  if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].distance < directionVector.length() )
  lockDirection();
  appendText(hits);

   }    `
```

Comment: I don't find there are `getDirection(), getObject()` in fps controls. try using `camera.getWorldDirection() , camera.getWorldPosition()` to get direction and position, your code looks fine. Or, if your mesh's material only in one side and you make the raycaster to intersect the wrong side would cause the problem.

Comment: excuse me is mode fps but is a pointerlockcontrols by videlais. I verify his code and getDirection and getObject  seems good.  I have verified the double side with add `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false } );` but i've not hit on intersect. By acquiring consciousness, i test with camera.getWorldDirection() , camera.getWorldPosition(), but i've not results.

Comment: I test with Pointerlockcontrols, `controls.getDirection` and `controls.getObject().position` work fine. and I can hit my boxes, I don't know what cause the problem, can u supply a complete HTML file so I can debug on it.

Comment: the controls is Pointerlockcontrol by videlais [link](https://gist.github.com/videlais/0a3cb2ca815422ab84442ce6c3c08f83)

Comment: the code is maj in first

Answer (score 0):

Your code work for me, I just changed a little bit, I use `ray.intersectObjects` instead of `intersectObject`, It works fine with three.js r85.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js - pointerlock controls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        body {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: arial;
        }
        
        #blocker {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        
        #instructions {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: box;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
            box-orient: horizontal;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
            box-pack: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            box-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="FirstPersonControls.js"></script>

    <div id="blocker">

        <div id="instructions">
            <span style="font-size:40px"></span>
            <br /> 
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var scene, anbientLight, controls, camera, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh, bbox;
        var collmeshList = [];
        var prevTime = performance.now();
        var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x020202);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            //////WORLD
            //FLOOR
            floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500);
            floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xff0000,
                wireframe: false
            });
            floorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
            floorMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
            floorMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            scene.add(floorMesh);

            //WALLS
            W01Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 200, 0.001, 8, 8);
            W01Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            W01Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(W01Geometry, W01Material);
            W01Mesh.position.z = -250;
            collmeshList.push(W01Mesh);
            scene.add(W01Mesh);

            W02Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 200, 0.001, 8, 8);
            W02Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            W02Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(W02Geometry, W02Material);
            W02Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
            W02Mesh.position.x = -250;
            //W01Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            collmeshList.push(W02Mesh);
            scene.add(W02Mesh);

            W03Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 200, 0.001, 8, 8);
            W03Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            W03Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(W03Geometry, W03Material);
            W03Mesh.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 2;
            W03Mesh.position.x = 250;
            collmeshList.push(W03Mesh);
            scene.add(W03Mesh);

            W04Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 200, 0.001, 8, 8);
            W04Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            W04Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(W04Geometry, W01Material);
            W04Mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            W04Mesh.position.z = -250;
            collmeshList.push(W04Mesh);
            scene.add(W04Mesh);

            //wallGroup = new THREE.Group();
            //wallGroup.add(W01Mesh, W02Mesh, W03Mesh, W04Mesh);
            //wallGroup.position.y = 50;
            //scene.add(wallGroup);

            //OBSTACLES
            B01Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
            B01Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            B01Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(B01Geometry, B01Material);
            B01Mesh.position.z = -100;
            B01Mesh.position.y = 25;
            collmeshList.push(B01Mesh);
            scene.add(B01Mesh);

            B02Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
            B02Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                wireframe: false
            });
            B02Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(B02Geometry, B02Material);
            B02Mesh.position.z = 100;
            B02Mesh.position.y = 25;
            collmeshList.push(B02Mesh);
            scene.add(B02Mesh);

            //////PLAYER
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 40;
            camera.position.z = 50;
            camera.updateMatrix();

            //////CONTROLS CAMERA
            controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
            scene.add(controls.getObject());

            //////RENDU
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        }

        function clearText() {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '..........';
        }

        function appendText(txt) {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += txt;
        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            playerControls();

            collupdate();

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

        function playerControls() {

            //unlockAllDirection();

            // Are the controls enabled? (Does the browser have pointer lock?)
            if (controls.controlsEnabled) {

                // Save the current time
                var time = performance.now();
                // Create a delta value based on current time
                var delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

                // Set the velocity.x and velocity.z using the calculated time delta
                velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
                velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

                // As velocity.y is our "gravity," calculate delta
                velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass

                if (controls.moveForward) {
                    velocity.z -= 400.0 * delta;
                    // Nothing to do!
                }

                if (controls.moveBackward) {
                    velocity.z += 400.0 * delta;

                }

                if (controls.moveLeft) {
                    velocity.x -= 400.0 * delta;

                }

                if (controls.moveRight) {
                    velocity.x += 400.0 * delta;

                }

                // Update the position using the changed delta
                controls.getObject().translateX(velocity.x * delta);
                controls.getObject().translateY(velocity.y * delta);
                controls.getObject().translateZ(velocity.z * delta);

                // Prevent the camera/player from falling out of the 'world'
                if (controls.getObject().position.y < 10) {

                    velocity.y = 0;
                    controls.getObject().position.y = 10;

                }

                // Save the time for future delta calculations
                prevTime = time;

            }
        }

        function collupdate() {

            //clearText();

            var cameraDirection = controls.getDirection(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)).clone();
            //direction.applyQuaternion(cameraDirection.quaternion);
            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(controls.getObject().position, cameraDirection);
            var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(collmeshList, true);
            if (intersects.length > 0)
                console.log('intesected');
            //appendText(hits);

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank  i see intersects in console since I export code in web. in local I have no text in console. if I understand what is happening, it counts the intersections it finds and when I come in contact with an object, it marks me intersected. What I do not understand is why it stops counting when I look to the ground, why there is a delay time before it shows me intersected and why controls become difficult when I'm colluding With an object. my objective is that the control is blocked when one is in collusion with an object. you see here [link] (http://www.macabann.com/gallery/index6.html)